# Drop Commit is disabled in WebStorm's Git

Tags: git, intellij-idea, webstorm

The WebStorm's Git context menu has "Drop Commits" entry disabled:

[image]

This happens when the default branch is named "master". If the name is "main" – everything is OK.

How can I make this available when the branch name is "master"?

Answer (score 5):

Rebase-based operations are disabled for commits pushed to a protected branch.
`master` is protected by default, that is why it is disabled.

The list of protected branches can be configured in **Settings/Preferences | Version control | Git** using semicolon `;` as a separator (e.g. `master;main`).

Actually the reason why the action is disabled is written on the status bar, lower-left corner on the screenshot, but that is not very noticeable.

Comment: «The list of protected branches can be configured in Settings | Version control | Git» - How can l do it?

Comment: @maxim.saharov *"`Settings | Version control | Git` How can l do it?"* Which part do you have a problem with? 1) You do not know how to open WebStorm Settings (it's called Settings on Windows and Linux but Preferences on Mac)? 2) You cannot locate "Version Control | Git" there? 3) Or you cannot find the "Protected branches" field there for some reason? Please clarify this. https://i.imgur.com/uQ3f6GQ.png

Comment: @LazyOne How add a few protected branches? 
If i write "master, main" - doesn't work any protection.

Comment: @maxim.saharov https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-version-control-git.html#47413ecc *"You can list several branches separated by a semicolon, or supply branch patterns as the input is treated as a list of regular expressions."* -- use semicolon `;` as a separator. Does it work?

Comment: @LazyOne Like this "master;main" – everything is OK, thanks.